# Is it safe to dual boot ubuntu in c drive running windows 7?

Tags: dual-boot

I have instlled windows 7 in my pc. I need a linux os, hence i chose Ubuntu. Can i install Ubuntu in my c drive ?

Comment: Linux does not understand "C drive". It is critical you make backups of your data and that you understand linux partitioning BEFORE you install. FWIW linux uses /dev/sda for the drive and /dev/sdax for partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu itself will not harm you PC or your HDD, but as always user error can occur.  If you are diligent about making backups of important data, you will save yourself from a great deal of frustration later.

Comment: I asked .. whether i can install it in my c drive

Comment: It can be done and [Ubuntu has a guide to this process](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) assuming you want to have both operating systems on your computer.

Comment: Nevertheless, please *please* follow the advice here, and have a backup ready. Installing an operating system is not the same as installing another program, and things can go horribly wrong sometime. I installed my first Linux in the 90ies, and I've been system manager, so I can say I am quite an expert, but I *never* install an operating system without a recent, verified backup.

Comment: @Rmano I hope people get the idea about make a backup!  I mentioned it, you mentioned it, the Ubuntu guide above talks about it...